# Problems installing r.roughness

Tags: grass-gis, installation, extensions, grass.script

I am trying to install r.roughness in GRASS 6.4.3. 
It starts compiling but at the end I get this error:

```
ERROR: Module did not install properly
```

I cannot identify the problem.
Can somebody that has come across the same error help me?

Answer (score 1):

The installation procedure in the addon is not right, the author should fix it. Meanwhile you can simply download the script(s) from here:

https://svn.osgeo.org/grass/grass-addons/grass6/raster/r.roughness/